# Producing a VHDL design unit from a State Diagram

Tags: vhdl, state-machines

I need help understanding a stateflow diagram.
I'm supposed to design it in VHDL as a beginner's exercise.

I've gone through the VHDL tutorials on nandland.com, and could say I understand the basics of VHDL.

What I don't understand is what this state diagram means.[image]

Could someone help me with that? You don't have to write the code, I just need to know what the diagram means.

Noob question, I know. But I'm new to this.

Thanks in advance.

Edit:
Here's where I got the question from. The question says I should replace X with 0.
[image]

Comment: Where did you get the diagram? Unfortunately, state diagram notation is not completely standardized. Also, I think there is a problem with the diagram you have shown, unless there is some explanation that goes along with it.

Comment: As far as I can tell, your questions has nothing to do with VHDL but is rather about what exactly a Mealy state machine diagram represents.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mealy_machine

Answer (score 2):

What you have there is the state diagram of a Mealy Statemachine (en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mealy_machine)

It's a very simple one that has only 1 input and 1 output, that's what the notation on the transition arrows represents (input/output). 
I'm wondering where you found this diagram, because it doesn't make much sense.
So what this diagram technically illustrates is the following

- Let's assume the entry point is SA (State-A)
- If your input is '1', the transition guard to SB is true, so you change to SB and set the output to '0'. At SB (State-B) you have the same transition guard to SC (State-C) and again the output is '0' - so for now this is your final state.

What's rather strange are the two transition guards between SA and SC, both have a guard of input '0', this means from any of the 3 states you'll end up toggling between these two states as long as your input is '0' - as correctly mentioned in the comment, the output would toggle as well.

Comment: You'll end up toggling between the states and also toggle your output. It's basically a clock gate.